# Sizing button on ionic 2 with col

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

A very simple problem,

I want all my button to take 90 % of the width of my columns in ionic 2, and not be dependent of the text inside

```
.button-pink {
    color: #F63566;
    background-color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 75%;
    border: 2px solid #F63566;
    padding: 6% 23%;
    margin: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "SanFranciscoText-Regular";
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
}
```

here is my button css, i can't manage to make them fit the width of the column, and not be dependent of the text (if i change the text inside my button, the size is changing, and i don't want that)

Thank you in advance and good day to everyone !

Comment: Have you tried adding `width: 90%`

Comment: working like a charm perfect, add this answer to my question and i will validate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the width of the button in your CSS.

```
.button-pink {
  width: 90%;
}
```